# True Image scheduled backups failing because the removable device drive letter changes

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, acronis-trueimage, removable-media

I have Acronis True Image setup to backup to an external hard drive. I keep getting the error message "Please insert the last media of the archive and click Retry to continue". I think this is happening because the drive letter  changes e.g. from F: to G: so the path to F:\Acronis\Backups is now invalid. How do I fix this? Honestly I found True Image to be too complex for my needs and the settings are too much.

Comment: Is the external hard drive meant for backup purposes only?

Comment: Why don't you configure Windows to assign the same letter to the drive?

Comment: @and31415 no...

Comment: @Ramhound how??

Comment: @Celeritas See [How can I permanently assign drive letters to my USB devices in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/306782/how-can-i-permanently-assign-drive-letters-to-my-usb-devices-in-windows) Keep in mind Windows will give the assigned letter to the drive only if it's actually available. For this reason it's better to assign a letter farther down the alphabet. As an alternative you could mount the drive to an empty NTFS folder.