# How best to manage mapping drive letters?

Tags: windows-8.1, usb-flash-drive, nas, mapped-drive

I have the below configuration on my home computer:

- `C`: Operating system (Windows 8.1)
- `D`: SSD (quick scratch drive)
- `E`: Large HDD (large storage)
- `F`: Optical drive
- `I`: NAS storage directory #1
- `J`: NAS storage directory #2
- `K`: NAS storage directory #3

I would have thought that when I attach a USB memory stick to my computer it would get automatically assigned to the next available letter (eg `G` in this case).

However, instead, when I do this, it gets assigned to `I`. The drive still shows up in 'My Computer' as "NAS storage directory #1" but when I open it, it shows the contents of the USB memory stick....and then when I remove the memory stick the drive mapping is crossed out and I have to manually remap the letter to the NAS directory.

Comment: You may want to know how to assign a fixed drive letter for the usb drive http://superuser.com/questions/306782/how-can-i-permanently-assign-drive-letters-to-my-usb-devices-in-windows