# See a drive's default letter assignment

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

A drive is not always assigned the same letter. For example, in case of multiple concurrently connected flash drives, a flash drive's assigned letter will depend on the order that they were connected. A drive does, however, have a default letter that it will be assigned [if that letter is not taken yet](https://superuser.com/a/306789/125659)  .

How can I see a drive's default letter even if it's not using that letter now?